# Is possible with django-autocomplete-ligth to browse relateds objects

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I would like to browse related objects in addition to search . like in the raw_id_field widget in the admin.

Is it possible with django-autocomplete-light?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not with DAL, but you can certainly implement [such thing](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/20001556462/howto-javascript-popup-form-returning-value-for). The article is about populating an HTML select field with a JS popup, but you can just omit that part and populate a text input instead like raw_id_field, all the rest of the article is valid for your case.